# Following Rotting Links

Tags: knowledge, cipher, geography

Here's some examples of rotting links. Why are they rotting, and what links them?

[image]

> Lebanon - ROT -> Slovenia
> Monaco - ROT -> Slovenia
> European Union - ROT -> Slovenia - ROT -> Antarctica

[image]

> Brunei - ROT -> Haiti - ROT -> Malaysia - ROT -> Uganda - ROT -> Armenia - ROT -> Haiti

[image]

> Trinidad And Tobago <- ROT -> Myanmar

[image]

> People's Republic of China - ROT -> People's Republic of China

[image]

> Antigua and Barbuda - ROT -> Tanzania - ROT -> Bahrain - ROT -> British Indian Ocean Territory - ROT -> Montserrat
> Ukraine - ROT -> Bahrain

And finally some that don't rot at all (at least, not currently)

[image]

> Mongolia, Sri Lanka, Latvia, Kiribati, Kazakhstan, Lithuania

<sup>In the case of discrepancies, the images take precedence</sup>

Comment: Oh... Trinidad and Tobago...

Comment: @WhatsUp am I missing something?

Comment: No no, I just find it funny that it wears a ring!

Comment: @WhatsUp ah, yes, that's nothing to do with the puzzle by the way. You only need the text and the links to be able to figure it out (hopefully!) - I'll add in the transcription shortly

Comment: This is a brilliant puzzle!

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Thanks! What do you like about it?

Comment: it is just so clever!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One country links to another by

> taking the [country code internet domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Country_code_top-level_domains) and ROT-ing it forward by the number of letters in the country name, *including punctuation and spaces*. ROT here is a [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher), or **rot**ation cipher.

For example,

> Lebanon is **.lb** and length 7 
>  -> ROT7(**lb**) = **si**, or Slovenia. 
>  Then, Slovenia is length 8 
>  -> ROT8(**si**) = **aq**, which is Antarctica. 
>  Then, Antarctica is length 10 
>  -> ROT10(**aq**) = **ka**, which is not a used domain, so there's no outgoing link.

Interestingly, People's Republic of China is

> 26 characters, and since ROT26(**cn**) = **cn**, it links to itself.

All of them:

> Lebanon: ROT7(lb) = si, Slovenia 
>  Monaco: ROT6(mc) = si, Slovenia 
>  European Union: ROT14(eu) = si, Slovenia 
>  Slovenia: ROT8(si) = aq, Antarctica 
>  Antarctica: ROT10(aq) = ka, no link
>  
>  Brunei: ROT6(bn) = ht, Haiti 
>  Haiti: ROT5(ht) = my, Malaysia 
>  Malaysia: ROT8(my) = ug, Uganda 
>  Uganda: ROT6(ug) = am, Armenia 
>  Armenia: ROT7(am) = ht, Haiti 
>  
>  Trinidad and Tobago: ROT19(tt) = mm, Myanmar
>  Myanmar: ROT7(mm) = tt, Trinidad and Tobago
>
>  People's Republic of China: ROT26(cn) = cn, People's Republic of China
>  
>  Antigua and Barbuda: ROT19(ag) = tz, Tanzania
>  Tanzania: ROT8(tz) = bh, Bahrain
>  Bahrain: ROT7(bh) = io, British Indian Ocean Territory
>  British Indian Ocean Territory: ROT30(io) = ROT4(io) = ms, Montserrat
>  Montserrat: ROT10(ms) = wc, no link
>  
>  Mongolia: ROT8(mn) = uv, no link 
>  Sri Lanka: ROT9(lk) = uv, no link 
>  Latvia: ROT6(lv) = rb, no link 
>  Kiribati: ROT8(ki) = sq, no link 
>  Kazakhstan: ROT10(kz) = uj, no link 
>  Lithuania: ROT9(lt) = uc, no link

Comment: Good spot, well done